# Overriding the x getter in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, position, overriding, movieclip, getter

I have a class called `Element`. It is basically my ultra-movieclip, and nearly all classes in the game subclass it. `Element` extends Movieclip

The code in the game is built around the idea that all Movieclips are registered at the top-left corner. Register it somewhere else, and everything starts to fall apart.

The problem is, sometimes the in the animation and such, the top-left corner moves, but the registration point doesn't, and you end up with a registration point somewhere in the middle of the Movieclip. This causes problems.

So, how do I fix this problem? We can find the true top-left corner of a Movieclip using `getBounds` ([this is the documentation for it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001298.html/)), but using `getBounds` over and over in code would get kinda tedious.

My idea is to override the `x` getter in the `Element` class. That way, we can always know where the `Element`'s true top-left corner is, without having to write a bunch of complicated code every time!

And for the sake of argument, let's assume that just making a new getter like "`trueX`" will open a trapdoor beneath my feet and plunge me into a cage of starving gophers.

I cannot figure out how to override the `x` getter! How can we do this? Have I missed an incredibly simple solution to the problem that has nothing to do with overriding?

```
override public function get x():Number {
    //I have no idea what I'm doing!
}
```

Comment: So... what isn't working?  Your override code is valid (though it won't actually do anything).  Are looking for advice of what code to put into the override?  You're looking to get an offset of the true x value to account for the children bounds?    also, you should really feed those gophers....

Comment: if you mean rotation and such you'll need to find another way. Modifying the x getter means returning wrong values for simple x position which might also cause problems further down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be all you need to do: (if I understand your question right)

```
override public function get x():Number {
    return super.x + getBounds(this).x;
}
```

Comment: haha you are right, I have decided to feed those darn gophers. and uproot most of the code in my program...